# Unclaimed bounties

Tags: discussion

If you offer a bounty and it goes unclaimed ([without even an answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/using-pathfinders-variant-wounds-and-vigor-rules)), what happens to the bounty?  Just curious...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are no answers, then the bounty disappears and is not refunded.

Other situations were answered on meta.stackexchange.com.  [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Incidentally, the [Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) is a great place to find answers to how things work in the general case.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply; I searched on meta.rpg, but didn't think about meta.stackoverflow.

Comment: The lack of a refund when there are no acceptable answers always makes me sad :(

Comment: @SimonWithers You just need to spruce up the question then.